# jquery ui images failed to load in chrome extension manifes json

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

```
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["jquery.js", "contentScript.js", "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"],
      "css":["jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css","jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "jquery-ui/images*.png"
  ]
```

The images of jquery-ui still doesn't load. Is there anything wrong with my manifest.json? or path? I put images same level with jquery-ui.js and its css.

Comment: check all your brackets. is they are placed right?

Comment: Chrome version? Do the files exist? What error are you seeing in the console?

Comment: @RobW no error.. latest chrome (37)

Answer (score 1):

take alook at the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest
content_scripts required a "matches" attribute.

also in resources list your js and css files.